# I/O Stream manipulator - adjustfield internal - C++ vs C

Tags: c++, c, io, printf, cout

Programmer student here.  I'm having trouble with one portion of my class assignment.  Our task is to convert a C++ program into a C program.
There is one line of code I'm having trouble converting because of the use of "internal" stream manipulator.  It needs to look something like this in the output:

`+       6443.` or `-       6443.`

But I can't seem to make that happen using C standard rather than C++

Here's the code in C++ that I'm supposed to convert:

```
cout << setprecision(4) << setw(13) << internal << showpoint << showpos << fourth << endl;
```

I've tried this, but the +/- are still right next to the number.

```
printf("%+13.0f. \n", fourth);
```

Here is the entire program if it is easier to understand in its entirety...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    //bool first;           //Changing data type for standard C Input
    int first;              //This is in place of the bool
    int second;
    //long third;           //Changing data type for standard C input
    int third;              //This is in place of long
    float fourth;
    float fifth;
    //double sixth;         //Changing data type for standard C input
    float sixth;            //This is place of double

    //cout << "Enter bool, int, long, float, float, and double values: ";
    printf("Enter bool, int, long, float, float, and double values: ");
    //cin >> first >> second >> third >> fourth >> fifth >> sixth;
    scanf("%d %d %d %f %f %f", &first, &second, &third, &fourth, &fifth, &sixth);
    //cout << endl;
    printf("\n");

    //1 - 3
    printf("%d", first);

    if(first > 0)
        printf(" true \n");
    else
        printf(" false \n");

    printf("%d %#x %#o \n", second, second, second);
    printf("%16d \n", third);

    //4
    //cout << setprecision(4) << setw(13) << internal << showpoint << showpos << fourth << endl;
    printf("%+13.0f. \n", fourth); //Issues

    //5
    printf("%15.4e\n", fourth);

    //6
    //cout << left << setprecision(7) << fifth << endl;
    printf("%-.7e \n", fifth); //Issues

    //7 - 12
    printf("%17.3f \n", fifth);
    printf("%-d \n", third);
    printf("%16.2f \n", fourth);
    printf("%13.0f \n", sixth);
    printf("%14.8f \n", fourth);
    printf("%16.6g \n", sixth);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  This is what I ended up using and it worked with my professors test driver every time  Yay!     

    printf ("%c %10.0f. \n", (fourth < 0.0f) ? '-':'+', fabs(fourth));

Answer (score 1):

output the '+' or '-' as a separate %c parameter,

```
printf( "%c%13d\n",( (forth >=0)? '+' : '-' ), abs(forth) );
```